# Why does this button click keep causing app to crash

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Hi im new to programming. I have a button that when clicked should change the image of an imageView to a different image. But when the button is clicked the app crashes. Im sure its something small im missing. Iv looked up the errors and cant seem to find anything can help sort out this problem. Im thankful for any help I can get.

```
public class MonthSelect extends Activity {

    //declaring variables
    ImageView image;
    Button jan;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_month_select);

        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    private void addListenerOnButton() {
        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.monthDisplay);

        jan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.januaryButton);
        jan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.a_10);

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.month_select, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

the xml with imageview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".MonthSelect" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/monthDisplay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/month_quote_display"
        android:src="@drawable/a_1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the errors

```
05-07 08:22:10.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7415): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 08:22:10.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7415): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 08:22:10.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7415):     at com.learning.MonthSelect$1.onClick(MonthSelect.java:54)
05-07 08:22:10.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7415):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)
05-07 08:22:10.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7415):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17072)
05-07 08:22:10.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7415):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-07 08:22:10.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7415):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-07 08:22:10.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7415):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
05-07 08:22:10.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
05-07 08:22:10.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7415):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 08:22:10.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7415):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-07 08:22:10.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7415):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
05-07 08:22:10.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7415):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
05-07 08:22:10.464: E/AndroidRuntime(7415):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: where is your button in layout ?

Comment: What is line 54 of MonthSelect.java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your you need to have R.id.januaryButton in  activity_month_select layout

if you nead to display image in new window just create another activity with your image layout as contentview, then call the  activity with image from the activity with button in the onclick function of button.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `Button jan` in your `activity_month_select.xml` file and you still create `jan`

```
jan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.januaryButton);// Cause Null Pointer Exception
```

You need to add `Button` with id `januaryButton` in your layout file.

Comment: But wouldn't that lead to an NPE in onCreate instead of onClick?

Comment: The button is in a different xml layout. What im trying to do is when the button is clicked it opens another xml layout with just an image view. Am im doing this all wrong

Comment: He needs both a button and imageview in his layout

Answer (score 0):

It seems the layout you posted is *not* `R.layout.activity_month_select`, but a separate one that contains the ImageView you use as well.
From what I can see from the logs, it seems `R.layout.activity_month_select` actually contains the button with the ID `R.id.januaryButton`, but not the `ImageView` `R.id.monthDisplay`.

Make sure those (the Button and the ImageView) are both in `R.layout.activity_month_select`.